# rails exclude for multiple strings

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, string

I have the following code. This piece of code is working for me.But it looks ugly. is there any cleaner approach for achieving this?

```
<% if request.original_url.exclude?("/invest/") || request.original_url.exclude?("/study/") || request.original_url.exclude?("/work/") %>
 some html tags here ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `exclude?` is defined in Rails is defined just as the opposite of `include?`, which would be very good if it's able to receive a regular expression, but it doesn't.

What you can do is to store in an array the substrings you want to check against the `request.original_url`, and use any? to check if *any* of those return true, which helps you to save a bit of characters, but would be good if that list increases.

You can try something like this:

```
['/invest/', '/study/', '/work/'].any? { |e| request.original_url.exclude?(e) }
```

Comment: This is a good solution. Also in your use case it would be good to extract this to a helper method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use helper and add following codes in it

```
exclude_ursl(request)
url_rules = ["/invest/", "/study/", "/work/"]
   url_rules.each_with_object([]) do |url,urls|
      urls << (request.original_url.exclude?(url))
    end.include?true
end
```

Now use it in your view

```
<%if exclude_urls(request) %>

I don't have current such environment to test, so you can test it.
```